# passing data from service to an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

If I put my service and activity in the same package, Can I exchange data between them using some global variables? I want optimized performance, so, global variables idea seems good but is it possible? If not, what is the best option. If intents is the way to go, then would the performance be good enough? BTW, the service has a big hashMap (may be multiple). This map needs to be accessed by the activity?

Thanks,
Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

I know if you have multiple activities in a project, it's possible to start up one activity with certain args.

http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-pass-data-to-activity.html

This might not be what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. They are volatile due to the activity lifecycle, so you run the risk of having them garbage collected.

You can accomplish what you want using ResultReceivers. Here's a nice tutorial:

http://lalit3686.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/how-to-update-activity-from-service.html